# How to add 1 to the leaderboard everytime this button is clicked?

Tags: button, lua, roblox, leaderboard

I am trying to make a script where when you click this button, the leaderboard adds 1. This is what i got so far:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function leaderboardSetup(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local gold = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gold.Name = "Gold"
    gold.Value = 0
    gold.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local function upd()
        gold.Value = gold.Value + 1
    end
    
    game:GetService("StarterGui").ScreenGui.TextButton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(upd)
    
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(leaderboardSetup)
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Did you try using `player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you used is grabbing the StarterGui object. That object is cloned into the PlayerGui of the player.

To properly connect this, create a remoteEvent inside of ReplicatedStorage and name it "GoldClick"

In ServerScriptService use a script like this

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function leaderboardSetup(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player

    local gold = Instance.new("IntValue")
    gold.Name = "Gold"
    gold.Value = 0
    gold.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local function upd()
        gold.Value = gold.Value + 1
    end
    game.ReplicatedStorage.GoldClick.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Localplayer)
        if player.Name == Localplayer.Name then
           upd()
        end
    end)
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(leaderboardSetup)
```

Then, create a LocalScript inside of the button and use the code below

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
game.ReplicatedStorage.GoldClick:FireServer()
end)
```